# Numbers not treated as numbers

Tags: string-manipulation, dataset

I'm apologize for the stupidity of this question, but I've run out of ideas.  I have some data saved in a mx file.  When imported, MM isn't treating the values as numbers.

For instance:
`Freedonia = Import["dataFreedonia.mx"] // Dataset;`

This imports the data:

[image: Import data]

So far so good.  But when I do something as basic as take a mean:

[image: Mean value]

It is like it doesn't understand that the two values are numbers.  So I tested that:

[image: NumberQ]

I've also tried using ToExpression in case it thought the values were strings; that failed.

Anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT**

In response to the comment by J.M., I've tried to replace the scientific form using the Identity function.  This still doesn't seem to solve the issue, but it does seem that we are on the right track:

[image: Using Identity]

Comment: What does `FullForm[Freedonia[1, 2]]` return?

Comment: [martinky](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/114869/52) is likely correct. But, it should be noted that `NumberQ` is more restrictive than `NumericQ` as `NumberQ[Pi]` is `False`. But, that isn't likely to apply in this case.

Comment: J.M.:  ScientificForm[0.03958551390946177`,5]

Comment: martinky, I've also tested this with NumericQ and it also returns false.

Comment: Well, that's why you're having problems. Try making the replacement `Freedonia /. ScientificForm -> Identity` and report back.

Comment: J.M.  Thank you for the suggestion.  I've updated the question above.  The Identity function doesn't seem to work on the entire dataset object, but it does work on the individual elements.  However, once converted, it still doesn't want to evaluate (e.g. take a mean).

Comment: Hmm, I forgot the exact form of `ScientificForm[]` for some reason; anyway, the replacement rule ought to have been `Freedonia /. ScientificForm[n_, rest___] -> n`. Try that, please.

Comment: @tazz_ben Why are you using `Dataset`? It adds nothing to your list.  You don't need it.